# rstudio ANSI escape sequences not working correctly

Tags: r, rstudio, ansi-escape

I am playing with ANSI colors in the rstudio terminal, and found the following problem.

If I set the background to very light grey (255), then the ANSI sequence for default background does not work:

```
## This works
cat("\033[48;5;254mOne\033[49mTwo\n")
## This doesn't
cat("\033[48;5;255mOne\033[49mTwo\n")
```

[image]

As you can see, the first variant (with 254) correctly restores the default background, while the second doesn't.

The same stuff happens if I use 255 as the foreground color – the default foreground color does not get restored:

```
## This works
cat("\033[38;5;254mOne\033[39mTwo\n")
## This doesn't
cat("\033[38;5;255mOne\033[39mTwo\n")
```

Both variants work correctly in a standard Ubuntu terminal.

Is there anything special about 255, am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Rstudio Version 1.2.5042
R version 3.6.3

Comment: Which RStudio version, which OS?

Comment: I added the information.

Comment: You should report this as a bug.